# Как на idea запустить проект на tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

Как на idea запустить проект на tomcat?

В eclipse все просто

*Run->run on server и -> настройки сервера ВСЕ*

Как это сделать на idea?

Comment: Какая версия IDEA? Если Community, то никак.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-auto-reload-a-web-application-hot-deploy/ - мне очень помогло

Answer (score 4):

Сначала устанавливаешь томкат, затем создаешь системную переменную *CATALINA_HOME*. Создаешь проект, потом в IDEA нажми на кнопку Select run/Debug configuration, оттуда выбери себе tomCat local, потом в демлоймантах укажи свои варник, джарник или еарник.

И самое важное: тебе нужно IDEA ULTIMATE, в комюнити многое урезали, в том числе томкат.

Answer (score 0):

Более простой, как по мне, вариант при сборке через Maven - использовать плагин Tomcat:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
            <server>TomcatServer</server>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Работает также и в CE версии.
Далее в меню запуска появится среди плагинов Tomcat7: запуск, дэплой...